# USB modem dosn't working in Ubuntu

Tags: internet, usb-modem

In Ubuntu 12.10 USB-modem Huawei 171 from MTS is not connected to the network. First on the message `Are you registered on the network`, immediately after that, `You are disconnected from the network.`

This happened after there was an internal error notification Ubuntu. I did not pay attention, and closed by sending the report. After the reboot does not work. Settings are not changed. I am online with this modem in Windows 8. Could you tell me why it is not working, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st of all you have to create a network to connect to internet.

1. insert the modem
2. click on the network icon.
   there you will be asked to enable mobile broadband.
3. click on the new broad band connection.
4. follow the steps and finish.
5. now edit connection and enter this value in the mobile broadband tab.

   username: `MTS`

   password :`internet`
6. save it.

now connect and it will connect normally.

Comment: I have already done it

Comment: have you entered the username  and password carefully?